# How to render React Route component in an entirely new, blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to render a print page using React Router. So I have two components:

```js
export default class PurchaseOrder extends React.Component{
....
render(){
   const {orderDate, client} = this.state.order;
   //omitted for brevity
    return(
            <BrowserRoute>
              <Button
                component={Link}
                to="/order/print"
                target="_blank"
              >
                Print
              </Button>
              <Route
                path="/order/print"
                render={props => (
                  <OrderPrint
                    {...props}
                    orderDate={orderDate}
                    client={client}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </BrowserRoute>

   }
}
```

And the OrderPrint:

```js
export default function OrderPrint(props) {
  return (
    <div>props.orderDate</div>
    <div>props.client.name</div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to present the printable version of the purchase order with a click of a button. The OrderPrint component gets rendered, but it's rendered right below the button. I could put the Route inside my root component, which is App, that way making sure that I get only the contents of the OrderPrint component rendered like this:

```js
class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={PurchaseOrder} />
        <Route exact path="/order/print" component={OrderPrint} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

But in that case, I won't be able to pass the necessary props to it. So in this particular case, how to replace entire page content with the contents of OrderPrint component and still be able to pass the necessary input to it?

#### Update

As @Akalanka Weerasooriya mentioned in comments, I could have the entire state kept in the App component. But one thing stopped me from doing this: This means I'll practically always have to use the `render` prop of the Route component, instead of the `component` prop. Ok, that's not a problem, but if it's the way to go, then why does React Router documentation almost always use the

```js
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
```

pattern as the standard way of using it? So to recap it, if I go the Single Source of Truth way and store all my state in one place, then doesn't it mean that I will always use

```js
<Route path="/about" render={props=>(<div>props.someProp</div>)} />
```

I don't say there's a problem with it, it's just mentioning it in the documentation only after `component={SomeComponent}` pattern confuses me.

Comment: Have you considered keeping the {orderDate, client} on root level state and passing it to both routes as props?

Comment: maybe as a different tab / page and using [react portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to keep the data sync?

Comment: @AkalankaWeerasooriya, in fact,  I was eventually going to have my entire state in the root component. And your suggestion made me think it's already time. Just one thing was stopping me from doing this: This means I'll always have to use the `render` prop of the Route component as I practically always have to send the related state to the child of the App component. See the edits for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Sagivb.g, react portal is really a fantastic feature that can suit exactly this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need a different route for a print page, but anyway if you want it on a new empty page, you can take advantage of the [ReactDOM.createPortal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) feature.
You can create a new page and or even a new window using `window.open` while keeping the flow of react data in sync.

Here is a running example of a portal on a new window with live state updates from the component that triggered this window using a portal:

[running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nrj3xk3k2p), i'm sharing an external snippet and not using stack-snippets here because `window.open` returns `null` in the contexts of stack-snippets

Source code:

```
class WindowPortal extends React.PureComponent {
  containerEl = document.createElement("div");
  externalWindow = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { width = 450, height = 250, left = 150, top = 150 } = this.props;
    const windowFetures = `width=${width},height=${height},left=${left},top=${top}`;
    this.externalWindow = window.open("", "", windowFetures);
    this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.externalWindow.close();
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl);
  }
}

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    counter: 0,
    showWindowPortal: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        counter: state.counter + 1
      }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  toggleWindowPortal = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      showWindowPortal: !state.showWindowPortal
    }));
  };

  closeWindowPortal = () => {
    this.setState({ showWindowPortal: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Counter: {this.state.counter}</h1>

        <button onClick={this.toggleWindowPortal}>
          {this.state.showWindowPortal ? "Close the" : "Open a"} Portal
        </button>

        {this.state.showWindowPortal && (
          <WindowPortal closeWindowPortal={this.closeWindowPortal}>
            <h2>We are in a portal on a new window</h2>
            <h3>{`This is the current state: ${this.state.counter}`}</h3>
            <p>different window but sharing the state!!</p>

            <button onClick={() => this.closeWindowPortal()}>Close me!</button>
          </WindowPortal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That is in fact just what I needed. I too found Route too overkill for printing.

Comment: I've been trying to use react portal to print my react component. However, I'm stuck with a little problem. You see, the print button I'm going to have can't work as a state toggle button. A typical print button is a button that causes opening a print page as many times as you click it. In your example the toggleState changes the showPortal from true to false and vice versa which causes the render method to be called. In my case this won't work. I don't know, maybe I'm being too stupid to not see the simple solution, but can you suggest somethig that would work for print button?

Answer (score 1):

here you have a `PrivateRoute` which is a custom route which holds a header and header is rendered in `PrivateRoute` routes  only so when you try to navigate to new route like `path="/order/print"` then you won't get header which has button in it.

```js
function Header(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        component={Link}
        to="/order/print"
        target="_blank">
         Print</Button>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }) => {
  return <Route {...rest} render={props => {
    return <Layout>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Layout>
  }} />
}


export default class PurchaseOrder extends React.Component{

render(){
   const {orderDate, client} = this.state.order;
   //omitted for brevity
    return(
            <BrowserRouter>
              <div>
               <PrivateRoute exact path="/" layout={Header} component={Landing} />

              <Route
                path="/order/print"
                render={props => (
                  <OrderPrint
                    {...props}
                    orderDate={orderDate}
                    client={client}
                  />
                )}
              />
              </div>
            </BrowserRouter>

   }
}
```